# How to get all documents belong to specific subcollection using Flutter and Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say, I have this kind of architecture in Firestore;

```
   - Users (collection)
     - User A (document)
       - Notes (collection)
         - Note A (document)
         - Note B (document)
         - Note C (document)
     - User B (document)
       - Notes (collection)
         - Note D (document)
         - Note E (document)
         - Note F (document)
```

And I want to get all notes of all users' (Note A,B,C,D,E,F for this example)

How can I achieve that in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Collection Group query](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html) as follows:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('Notes').get();
```

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#collection-group-query):

> A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID. By
> default, queries retrieve results from a single collection in your
> database. Use a collection group query to retrieve documents from a
> collection group instead of from a single collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I access subcollection's document's parent? For this example: I want to access Note C's owner for example.

Comment: From one `Note` document, use the `parent` property => You get the parent collection. From this collection, use again the `parent` property => This time you get the parent document. That's it!

Comment: When I type snapshot.data!.docs[index].parent, I get this error : 'The getter 'parent' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'.'

Comment: `parent`is a property of a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) or of a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference). So you need to do `snapshot.data!.docs[index].ref.parent`.